# Why does User.count return 0, until bin/spring is restarted in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-spring

I run `bundle exec rails c`,

It goes to development environment.

When I do User.count I get 0 records.

1. But after I do `bin/spring stop` and then `bin/spring start`, I see
   User.count records as 23782. Why is it so?
2. What does spring do here?
3. What are its role and responsibilities?
4. Should I do this everytime?
5. Is this Spring same as Java Spring?